# How to get GoLand's flawless multi module support on VSCode (no go work)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, multi-module, goland, gopls

When I open my multi module project in GoLand (Jetbrains) it works amazingly, with *Implementations*, *Type Declarations* and other useful IDE features working fine out of the box.

But when I open that same project in VSCode, I cannot get intellisense to work (with `gopls`) it does not work and requires severe changes to the module structure with `go work`, (so it's not an option for me)

Is it because GoLand is using a different language server?

I tried experimenting with the Go extension settings which did not result in any benefit. I was able to disable the language server from turning everything red, but it is not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[go workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces) are part of the toolkit and should work on any IDE that supports the feature. I've been using it on VS Code on a daily basis.

So basically you need a `go.work` file in the project root and VS Code will interpret it. Example:

```golang
go 1.20

use (
    .
    ./mymodule1
    ./mymodule2
)
```

The difference is that GoLand [automatically adds](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/go-workspaces.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20go.work%20file%2C%20GoLand%20automatically%20adds%20all%20the%20modules%20in%20the%20project.) the modules in a multi-module setup, and I'm not aware of VS Code having this capability.

> When you create a go.work file, GoLand automatically adds all the modules in the project.

If you check Go's [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Go.gitignore) you'll see that the `go.work` file is ignored by default, so I would assume that you don't have it versioned. I usually comment that line so that VS Code keeps track of it and it goes into my commits.

```bash
# Go workspace file
go.work
```

To add new modules to `go.work` simply do `go work use .` from a new module root.

Sometimes I have to reload VS Code to sync it, but usually it works right away.

If you're still having issues, then probably it is worth trying [troubleshooting](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md) the extension.

Comment: I created a go.work file from GoLand and I am using that in VSCode and it works like a charm, thank you!